# How to Reverse iterate an array in c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to reverse iterate an array of strings.
The code below is working perfectly

```
QStringList aCodes;
aCodes<<"1"<<"2"<<"3"<<"4";
QStringList::iterator its;
for(its = aCodes.end()-1;its != aCodes.begin()-1;--its)
{
    qDebug()<<*its;
}
```

The code below is also working, but its is printing the last three strings only.

```
for(its = aCodes.end()-1;its != aCodes.begin();--its)
{
    qDebug()<<*its;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`QStringList` inherits `QList` which provides STL-like iterators, meaning it supports `reverse_iterator`. Note this is only available since Qt 5.6.

```
// Iterate in reverse with QList<T>::reverse_iterator (since Qt 5.6)
QStringList::reverse_iterator its;
for(its = aCodes.rbegin(); its != aCodes.rend(); ++its)
{
    qDebug() << *its;
}
```

Although not really an issue here, you should familiarize yourself with the [iterator sharing problem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#reverse_iterator-typedef) when using Qt containers and STL-like iterators.

In older versions of Qt that don't support `reverse_iterator`, you can at least use the bidirectional `iterator` as follows:

```
// Iterate in reverse with QList<T>::iterator
if (!aCodes.isEmpty())
{
    QStringList::iterator its = aCodes.end();
    do {
        --its;
        qDebug() << *its;
    } while (its != aCodes.begin());
}
```

Alternatively, you can use index-based iteration, which `QList` [is designed for](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#details).

```
// Iterate in reverse with indices
for (int i = aCodes.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    qDebug() << aCodes[i];
}
```

Comment: And what about in case of QList. Can we use the reverse_iterator there as well.

Comment: Yes, the point is that this is provided by `QList` so that includes anything derived from it.

Comment: I am using C++11. As much as i know reverse_iterator is not there in c++11.

Comment: Reverse-iterators in the standard library have been around for donkey's years. Are you saying it's not in Qt? Maybe you have an old version of Qt.

Comment: You are right, I am using Qt 5.5 and Reverse-iterator are not there in it.

Comment: in more recent Qt5, reverse iterator are present https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html. If possible for you, it should not be too costly to move to a more recent version.

Comment: @NeerajShukla I have updated the answer with alternatives for older Qt versions.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use an **vector** of **QString** like this

```
std::vector<QString> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (std::vector<QString>::reverse_iterator it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it)
{
    cout << *it;
} // prints 54321
```

Comment: He can also do that with a std::list.
For better readability, one can use auto instead or declaring the full length of the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a raw `for` loop altogether with `std::for_each` if you `#include <algorithm>`:

```
#include <algorithm>
std::for_each(std::rbegin(aCodes), std::rend(aCodes), [&](auto &ac) { qDebug() << ac; }
```

For more info, see cppreference on [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin).

Comment: Maybe is worth mentioning also a range based loop with `std::ranges::reverse_view`